# Which ways to clear array is better in this situation?

Tags: php, arrays

I intend to create a multidimensional array through a loop. My idea is that inside the loop function, I would assign elements into a single array, then the single array would assign into another big array before i empty the single array for the next loop process.

E.g.

```
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){
   $arr1['a'] = $i;
   $arr1['b'] = $i+=2;
   $arr2[] = $arr;  //assign the arr1 into the arr2
   $arr1= []; //clear arr1 again for the next looping
}
var_dump($arr2);
```

And the the result would be:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'a' => int 0
      'b' => int 2
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'a' => int 3
      'b' => int 5
```

However I find out that there are actually quite many ways to empty an array and Im not sure about that the way I empty the array is better/more efficient than the other ways such as `unset` or *reinitialize* the array like `$arr1 = array()`in this case. I look through online but there are not much in comparing these ways. Any suggestion to improve the performance on this or this is just as good as other ways? By looking at these:

```
unset($arr)
$arr = array()
$arr = []
```

And perhaps other ways?

Comment: Why clear the array at all? Its values are being overwritten each time.

Comment: My fault for being careless in this case. btw is there any suggestion to state that which way is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of making one extra array (smaller array) and then assigning the value to the bigger array, you can do something like this:

```
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){
      $arr2[$i]['a'] = $i;
      $arr2[$i]['b'] = $i+2;
    }
var_dump($arr2);
```

Output:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'a' => int 0
      'b' => int 2
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'a' => int 3
      'b' => int 5
```

In this case, you will not need to empty the (smaller) array again and again. Also it will save your memory space as you are using just one array.

Comment: Appreciate your answer and the output is the same with mine with cleaner code! btw any idea which type of _emptying array_ is better?

Comment: Using $arr1 = [] should be the most appropriate way.
Because unset($arr1) will destroy the array and then you will have to again define $arr1 by doing $arr1 = array(). So it increases the complexity of the program and makes your program little slower. So go with $arr1=[ ]

Comment: yeah I have the same concept for the `unset` too in this case

Answer (score 1):

If you want to execute a comparison, yo can do it with help of this code.

Ref: https://gist.github.com/blongden/2352583

It would look like so:

```
<?php

$calibration = benchmark(function() {

    for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){
          $arr2[$i]['a'] = $i;
          $arr2[$i]['b'] = $i+2;
        }

});

$benchmark = benchmark(function(){

    for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){
       $arr1['a'] = $i;
       $arr1['b'] = $i+=2;
       $arr2[] = $arr1;
       $arr1 = [];
    }

});

echo "Calibration run: ".number_format($calibration)."/sec\n";
echo "Benchmark run: ".number_format($benchmark)."/sec\n";
echo 'Approximate code execution time (seconds): '.number_format((1/$benchmark) - (1/$calibration), 10);

function benchmark($x)
{
    $start = $t = microtime(true);
    $total = $c = $loop = 0;
    while (true) {
        $x();
        $c++;
        $now = microtime(true);
        if ($now - $t > 1) {
            $loop++;
            $total += $c;
            list($t, $c) = array(microtime(true), 0);
        }
        if ($now - $start > 2) {
            return round($total / $loop);
        }
    }
}
```

Output for a test run in my env (PHP 7.2.8-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)

```
Calibration run: 258,534/sec
Benchmark run: 259,401/sec
Approximate code execution time (seconds): -0.0000000129
```

You will see that the given function by Nikhil is actually faster.

Output for the following function being run:

```
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){
      $arr2[$i]['a'] = $i;
      $arr2[$i]['b'] = $i+2;
    }

Calibration run: 209,614/sec
Benchmark run: 209,773/sec
Approximate code execution time (seconds): -0.0000000036
```

Feel free to play around your own tests

Comment: Thanks for the benchmark test ! You really did give me a better demonstration on performance comparison. However in this case the only i look at only focus on code execution time? How about the calibration and benchmark?

Comment: Sorry, I updated my post. You should put the tested function for calibration and benchmark. Do your run and get your output. Then replace for another function and run again to get a comparable value.

Comment: Yeah I did that and i did get comparison value for each test. May i know how to value the calibration and benchmark? Because they may high in calibration but low in benchmark (example).

Comment: Take calibration as a warm-up process for benchmark. This code may help you easily compare two functions performance, just for an estimative value. If you want more accurate benchmarking on your code consider learning on debugging tools like xdebug and benchmark like phpbench.